# How to add React Router to an existing create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

I can't find any tutorial showing how to add React Router to an existing create-react-app. All of them show how to do it when you start a fresh create react app. How do I add it to the half finished create-react-app I'm working on?

Comment: it suppose to be the same logic. import the package and call <Route><Router> to the places you wanna make use of. what problem you ran into?

Comment: Agreed with @Yuhao, also important for you to show us what problems you actually have. Please read the: [**mcve**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

1.install react-router-dom (v4).

```
import {Switch,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom';
```

2. import BrowserHistory,

   now you can use  Switch Route Components to play with routing.